# Why does derailed benchmark show different values in different systems? How to improve the memory allocation of ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, benchmarking

I installed [derailed-benchmark](https://github.com/schneems/derailed_benchmarks) gem to check memory usage of gems. I am also using personal gem.

1. When I execute the command:

   ```
   $ bundle exec derailed bundle:objects
   ```

   I get different memory values in different system:

   ```
   Measuring objects created by gems in groups [:default, "production"]
   Total allocated 433895
   Total retained 100556

   allocated memory by gem
   -----------------------------------
   24369241  activesupport-4.2.1
   15560550  mime-types-2.4.3
   8103432  json-1.8.2
   2170435  My-gem 0.1.0
   ```
2. Suppose my memory objects value of my gem is high. What do I need to do reduce that?